# Can I get Hyperdrive Upgrade Modules for my freighter outside Expedition Mode?

Tags: no-mans-sky

Having just played through Expedition 8, amongst other things I received a bunch of Freighter Upgrades as some of my milestone rewards.

This is one of them.

[image: Salvaged Hyperdrive Upgrade]

There were others; including one that provided 15% Trading Bonus, 15% Expedition Speed, and more.

My question is; can I get my hands on these anywhere outside Expedition 8?

It's my first experience with Expeditions, so wasn't giving this too much thought as I was playing through. And now I'm considering starting a *new* expedition playthrough, to win these rewards once more - only this time I want to transfer them onto my main save game.

Is there an alternative way, in a Normal Game Mode save?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Derelict Freighter

So it turns out, these can actually drop as reward from Derelict Freighter missions. I've been exclusively focusing on getting Bulkhead rewards from this to max out my freighter, never realising that the modules that drop here are actually freighter specific.

[image: Module Rewards from Derelict Freighter]

But as I understand it, they're not guaranteed to be S-Tier, this depends on the system you're in. So in any event, the ones we get from Expedition 8 are still valuable and will save you a lot of time running derelicts.

Source for the above: https://www.xainesworld.com/derelict-freighter-loot-tables-2-62/